# How to get file name and path using implicit intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, filter

I need to get the file name and path provided by implicit intent, I have tried getIntent().getdata().getpath(); methods but it doesn't works ,I'm new in android so please help me.
Here is my manifest code

`<intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/><category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/><data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
</intent-filter>`

And the code:

FILE file=new FILE(getIntent().getData().getpath());

Comment: Since that code will not even compile, we cannot help you with it, and you certainly are not using it. We also do not know what the "implicit intent" is that you are using. In general, you do not get "file name and path" in Android using `Intent` objects. You get a `Uri` value (`getIntent().getData()`), and that `Uri` does not have to point to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle receiving audio data like this (after testing for the expected action and MIME type):

```
Uri audoUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
if (audioUri != null) {
    // Use the Uri to read the audio file
}
```

Note that this gives you a [`Uri`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html), not a `File` object. If the sending activity created the `Uri` from a `File`, the `Uri` will have the form `"file://"`.